# How to retrieve any user's data from twitter

Tags: twitter, oauth

Is it possible to fetch (through twitter's API) specific user's data (like follower's id, or following user's id) without involve the user itself? I look forward to build twitter data miner but every tutorial i read involves end-users and pin authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Try [`Application-only authentication`](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only).

Get your keys and store it  in a separate file. Then use a streaming api & write a code to fetch what are all the data's you want (like follower's id, name etc..) & make that file to run as a background service that runs all the time.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With application-only authentication, still, do i need to authenticate users itself?

Comment: Generally you will have 4 keys. Consumer keys and Consumer secret for app. Access key and Access secret key for user. Visit [here](apps.twitter.com) to produce the Access key and Access secret for user and paste it. So, you don't need to authenticate, since you already have 4 keys. If it's normal, you'll only have Consumer key and Consumer secret and through authentication you get Access key and Access secret and you pass it in parameter. Hope you understand it.